# What else can be learned from the Installer.ProductInfo property?

Tags: vbscript, installation, windows-installer

Installer.ProductInfo is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I take [this](https://github.com/quad341/Conferenceware/blob/master/Conferenceware/App_Data/WiLstPrd.vbs) script, and I want to get various information (ex: UpgradeCode), where I can see all parameters, witch I cat set instead of "Version" (here installer.ProductInfo(product, "Version")). Yes, I see *For Each property In Array...*, but it is not enough for me (where "UpgreadeCode"?)). And where did this *Array*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full list of supported properties check the description of the *szProperty* parameter of the [`MsiGetProductInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130.aspx) function.

Most properties in this article are specified using predefined constants (e.g. `INSTALLPROPERTY_HELPLINK` instead of `"HelpLink"`); the actual string names of these properties are defined in the *msi.h* header file that is part of Windows SDK. A copy of *msi.h* v.4.0 can also be found online [here](http://vdfwinapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Include/Msi.h).

Comment: Thank you. There are really very few parameters. Can I get value of other Properties (not from szProperty list) by MsiGetProductInfo? By Installer.ProductInfo?